# cache only pictures on device from Json

Tags: android, json, caching

I have a Json object from a url, containing text and pictures.
But I dont know how to cache only the pictures on the device next time the user comes back and still get the text from the url?
Where to cache? On database or a folder in the device?

I have heard in iOS it can be done easily with NSCache but when searching the Web for an equivalent on Android I didnt find any.

Thanks!

Franck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the images using any image loader libraries like

> https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It'll handle caching efficiently

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So it cant be done without adding a library?

Comment: Yes..it can be done..just download the images into temp folder in initial call...nd on subsequent calls check whether you have the image downloaded and load it from there...else start the download process again..i mentioned the library coz it makes the task easier..it too follows the same logic..load from local temp folder if present else load from url